# Should I use "at every iteration" or "in every iteration"?

Tags: difference, expressions

Which one is correct "at every/each iteration" or "in every/each iteration"? I also have this confusion when using "step" instead of "iteration". More specifically, should I use "at each step" or "in each step"? Is there a difference in meaning between the usage of "in" and "at"?

Google Books Ngram Viewer shows that ["at each iteration" is the most common expression](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+each+iteration%2Con+each+iteration%2Cduring+each+iteration%2C+in+every+iteration&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20each%20iteration%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20each%20iteration%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cduring%20each%20iteration%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20every%20iteration%3B%2Cc0).

This type of expressions are often encountered in computer science. For example, in the paper [Metacontrol for Adaptive Imagination-Based Optimization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.02670), the authors often use "on each iteration".

Note: I'm not looking for an explanation in the specific context I've just mentioned (i.e. the paper I linked you to above), but general guidelines to follow.

Answer (score 2):

**at** refers to a point or a discrete event.

**in** refers to a context.

> At every iteration a counter is incremented.
>
> In every iteration several tasks are performed.

Comment: I said nothing about not being able to use **at** in #2. That is an inference you've drawn. But the nuanced difference is this: if you want to present the iteration as a context in which actions or tasks are carried out, use **in**.  If you want to present the iteration as a (recurrent) point in time, at which point actions are triggered, use **at**.  I'm trying to show you what **in** and **at** mean, not answer a question about which one is "right".